# DR RACKET DEFINE FUNCTIONS

Tags: racket

I am trying to program the formula `Distance-traveled= 2.5 *t^2`

I put 2.5 and the constant and the t is my seconds. The seconds is the varying input. I thought I defined everything okay but in the bottom window, when I try to call the function in hopes to find the distance traveled in 2 seconds, it says distance-traveled is not defined. What am I doing wrong? This is what I have in the top window

```
(define CONVERSION-FACTOR 2.5)

(define (distance-traveled seconds)
    ( * (* seconds seconds) CONVERSION-FACTOR))
```

This may help you guys help me!

[image: SCREEN SHOT OF CODE]

Comment: Have you tried to use lambda explicitly? `(define distance-traveled (lambda (seconds) ( * (* seconds seconds) CONVERSION-FACTOR)))`

Comment: We've never gone over using lambda, what does this do? Also is there a parenthesis missing there because it says it needs a fourth parenthesis at the end. I added it and now it says define: expected a variable but found a part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit shows us that you are using `distance-traveled` before it is defined. You need to place the definition of the function before you use it.

---

[image: Bad]

[image: Good]

Comment: Oh it worked! Thank you! But I thought when you are calling a function, it has to be done in the bottom window? Is that wrong?

Comment: The function can be called from anywhere, provided it has been defined. Your `check-expect` calls at the top were failing because they were trying to call `distance-traveled` before Racket got to the `define` statements. Put your `check-expect` statements at the _bottom_ of your code. This is separate from the two-windows issue, the bottom window is your Interactions window and the reason you couldn't call it from there was because when `check-expect` failed your program stopped running, so it actually never got to the `(define (distance-traveled seconds) ...)` part of your code at all!

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the **Run** button (or press <kbd>F5</kbd>).

Then your most-recent code edits in the *Definitions* (top or left) window will be available in the *Interactions* (bottom or right) window.

---

Edited to add some more explanation:

By default DrRacket *expands* your program while you type, to do syntax checking.

But that does not mean that it's actually *evaluating* your program, yet.

If you are just starting to learn Racket, "expand" vs. "eval" might seem like a distinction without a difference. It is roughly the same difference as macros vs. procedures, or compile time vs. run time. At this stage, just note that they are two distinct steps in Racket, and only the first one is necessary to do syntax checking. So even though the syntax checking might make you think that DrRacket has already "built" your program, it hasn't yet. You still need to do **Run** to expand *and* evaluate it.

To be super picky, Racket doesn't really have a REPL -- Read, Eval, Print Loop. Actually it's more like RECEPL -- Read, Expand, Compile (JIT), Eval, Print, Loop. But again, that's something you can probably wait to enjoy learning more about, later.

Comment: Yes I pressed the run button and then it goes past it and corrects another error I have in the code later on in the sequence (its a completely different question) so I assumed that Racket evaluated the distance traveled equation and it passed and went on the next problem. Is that assumption incorrect? If its right, then that means I should be able to call this function now as it is already defined, right?

Comment: Although that's an understandable assumption that's not how it works: If there are any errors, _none_ of the changes will take effect.